# JedisConnectionFactory that can handle TLS

Tags: spring-data-redis

I'm trying to configure caching with spring data redis over TLS. The existing code extends CachingConfigurerSupport. When creating a JedisConnectionFactory, I don't see any options to pass in something like 'rediss://my.redis.host'. I do see the 'useSsl' method on JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder, but don't see a place to specify a trust store. Has anyone been successful with JedisConnectionFactory and a TLS connection and could share some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `LettuceConnectionFactory` instead with the `LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.LettucePoolingClientConfigurationBuilder`.

Using the `RedisStandaloneConfiguration` you can pass in your host when you instantiate your `LettuceConnectionFactory`.